# trapezoids similarity

Tags: geometry

I found this geometry problem in an IGCSE text. Can't seem to find the missing lengths that they are asking for. I got an estimate for f (f=2.6666... cm) by drawing a line parallel to the left side of the trapezium that intersects the top right-hand vertex and forms two similar triangles.

is it just possible that some data is missing in this problem?

Screenshot of the problem with accompanying diagram:
[image]

Comment: Apologies for not mentioning this before. The info in that screen shot was all that was provided.

Comment: First thoughts: Looking at the angle that the slanted edge makes with the vertical edge, surely it must be true that
$$
\frac{4}{3} = \frac{f}{2}
$$
Do you agree?

Comment: @Indula Similar quadrilaterals work in much the same way as similar triangles

Comment: @ShubhamJohri But does equality of corresponding angles by itself imply similarity when it comes to polygons in general? I thought that equality of corresponding angles or the proportionality of corresponding sides are not sufficient conditions by themselves for establishing similarity between two polygons. That both are necessary and sufficient to establish similarity.

Comment: Yes, you could call it the '$AAAA$' criterion for quadrilaterals. Anywho, you could have a solution using triangles.

Comment: The two trapezoids are NOT similar. Having the same angles does not mean they are merely scaled up versions of one another. For example rectangles are not all similar - they are only similar if they have the same aspect ratio. However, in this problem, if you extend the sloped sides of the trapezoid till they meet, you can use three triangles, and triangles are similar if they have the same angles.

Comment: Actually, I think the base length $e$ can only be calculated if you also assume that the left side is perpendicular to the base.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis I tried extending the sides of the trapezium upwards to form a triangle and then using similarity properties of triangles to find the values *e* and *f*. Only to realise that without knowing the side lengths of the triangles thus formed I cannot find any scale factor that I can use to calculate e and f.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Tried that as well. But in the context of the problem, I don't think I have much wiggle room to assume that the left side is perpendicular to the base.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri I don't I think  need the "AAAA" level material to solve this seeing as I found it in an IGCSE textbook :D I was thinking along the same lines, that is, using similarity properties of triangles to get around a problem involving trapeziums. But just couldn't do it. Any hints for the way forward along that line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote that you drew a line parallel to the left side from the top-right corner down to the base. That line will also be split into lengths of exactly $3$ and $2$, just like the left side. This is because you have parallelograms on the left. This mean that the ratios on the triangles on the right is $3:(2+3)$, and this gives you that the right hand side of the trapezoid is $4*5/3=20/3$, making $f=20/3 - 4 = 8/3$.

To find $e$ you will have to make some assumption. From the right hand end of the horizontal line of length $6$, you can draw a line down to the base, parallel to the left side of the trapezoid. To the left of that line you have a parallelogram, so that line is of length $2$, and the part of the base to the left of it is of length $6$. So to find $e$, you need the part of the base to the right of it. That unknown part is the base of a triangle with sides $2$ and $f=8/3$. Unfortunately, it is impossible to find that third length unless we know one of the angles of that triangle.

To illustrate this, I have drawn the diagram in two ways:

[image]

You can clearly see the length of the base $e$ differs, even though the given lengths and the length of $f$ all remain unchanged.

Presumably the left side is supposed to be perpendicular to the base. In that case you can use Pythagoras to find out the exact length.

Comment: Thanks so much! There was a typo in the very first  post I made which indicated f=1.6666... which should have been f=8/3=2.666... Thanks for verifying my method for finding the length f. I was thinking about assuming that the trapezium is right-angled (it looks like that after all) and using the Pythagorean theorem to find the length e but was hesitant about explicitly adopting that assumption seeing as they haven't indicated that explicitly.

Comment: But on another note, if it hadn't been right-angled, and instead had been something akin to what you've sketched in your first diagram, is it possible to find the length, even if we knew the degrees of the angle?

Comment: Yes, in that case you will have to use the [law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines), which can be considered an extension of the Pythagorean theorem that works for an arbitrary angle, not just a right angle.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was really helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Since the trapezium is right, base length of smaller $\triangle$ by Pythagoras theorem is $\sqrt{4^2-3^2}=\sqrt{7}$.

So remnant of the base of smaller trapezium is $6-\sqrt{7}$.

Clearly $f=\frac83$ by similarity of triangles.

Now finding the base of bigger $\triangle$ (say $E$) by similarity of triangles:
$$\frac{E}{\sqrt{7}}=\frac{4+\frac83}{4}$$
or $E=\frac{5\sqrt7}{3}$

So that, $e=6-\sqrt{7}+\frac{5\sqrt7}{3}=6+\frac{2\sqrt7}{3}$.